# Timer triggers at scale

Tags: architecture

I am looking for some reference material/architecture/ experience for building timer triggers or reminder systems at scale.

A simpler question would be "how would you build Google reminders backend?"

I understand the notification delivery to clients. I am looking for suggestion on timer management.

How would trigger notification for many users? Do you use threads ? How do you maintain states?

Any suggestions on building timer trigger functions are also welcome.
Other example that could be related would be "how would you build the backed for timer triggered lambda functions or azure functions?"

Answer (score 1):

1. Keep a queue of reminders sorted by the moment they should go of.
2. Set a thread to wake up – moments before – the first one.
3. When the thread awakes, verify the time. There are three cases:

   - The notification should have happened at the past. You need to decide how are you going to handle this.
   - The notification should happen shortly in the future. Set a timeout to deliver the notification.
   - The notification should happen much later. Set the thread to sleep an adjusted time.
4. Monitor changes in the system clock.
5. If there is a change in system clock, a new reminder is set to before the first one, or when the notification is delivered... awake the thread so it can adjust for the next reminder.

At the time of a reminder, the process could have been preempted, the system could have been suspended, the process could have been stopped (which reminds me, the queue must be persistent). Because any of this, plus changes in system clock, including daylight saving and leap seconds... and also because timers are not precise enough... the thread could awake after the correct time.

Another situation is when you have multiple reminders that need to go at the same time, or nearly at the same time, such that delivering each will make it so the time instant for the next notification is in the past.

We want to minimize all that.

Thus, as you may imagine, it is a good idea to awake the thread a bit before it should go, and also we need to adjust to system clock changes... it is also a good idea to deliver the actual notifications in a different thread or threads. Furthermore, it is a good idea to bundle notifications, so that we do not really have multiple entries in the queue for the same time.

Which means that the main worker thread, the one reading from the reminders queue, will be pushing to a different queue from where the other threads pull... such that delivering the notifications does not block the main worker thread.

Depending on the load and external factors, there is still a chance that the main worker thread gets behind. You need to decide what happens in that situation... does it make sense to send notifications of things that passed? what if they are too many?

*I am mainly basing this answer in Channel 9 interview [Bart De Smet: Rx v2.0 Release Candidate - Time, Error Handling, Event Subscription](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Bart-De-Smet-Rx-20-RC-Time-Error-Handling-SafeSubscribe-and-More).*